# How do I determine the cause of resuming from hibernation in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, hibernate

My notebook sometimes resumes from hibernation without any apparent reason. This happens only when its plugged in power, LAN connection does not influence it.

Is there some log that would tell me why it resumed (what timer or device) so that I can disable it? Or can I start logging of it?

Answer (score 5):

You can use `powercfg` to find out what is waking up your computer.

> 1. Click on `Start`
> 2. Type `cmd` to open a command prompt
> 3. Type `powercfg -lastwake`

This will show you the particular USB or network device or event waking up your computer.

Comment: It seemed to work at the beginning. Sometimes it says (button, planned task...) , but sometimes the counter is empty, and  that is the case I am interested in...

Comment: For XP users, the equivalent command is powercfg -devicequery wake_armed

Comment: @Brian: I'm pretty sure that ´powercfg -devicequery wake_armed´ does under XP what it does under 7, i.e. show a list of devices that CAN wake the system. Not the one that DID wake the system last time.