# How to stop any resuming from hibernation in Windows

Tags: windows-7, windows, hibernate

I usually hibernate my Windows-7 Desktop PC during the night. Is there any way to tell Windows it should switch off the PC absolutely and utterly and completely, such that the only thing that can ever resume the PC is the power button? As it is, the keyboard lights are still on, and sometimes the PC is hanging in Bios password entry in the morning.

I know I can change which devices can wake up the PC [by using powercfg](https://superuser.com/questions/215558/how-do-i-determine-the-cause-of-resuming-from-hibernation-in-windows-7), but this is something I need to do again and again when I plug in the keyboard or the mouse into another USB port. Even is everything is switched off there, the keyboard lights are still on and the PC consumes unneccesary energy. Of course, I can also wait until the hibernation is complete and crawl under my desk every day to physically cut power, but I'd prefer Windows to behave decently. 8-/

CLARIFICATION: I do not want to shutdown but to hibernate since I do not want to wait for a couple of applications to start in the morning. Still, after writing the RAM content to disk, the PC has no business consuming any energy, anymore, or much less start itself without my consent.

Comment: Instead, put your computer to standby (S3) and check the event log after it woke up unexpectedly. There will be an entry about the device causing the wake-up. Common perpetrators include mouse, keyboard and automatic updates (set to 3 AM by default).

Comment: @DanielB I did this, and currently there are no wakeup timers nor devices able to wakeup the PC left. But the keyboard lights are still on. I also hope that there is some way to avoid this procedure, since after plugging e.g. a keyboard into another USB port Windows seems to decide that this keyboard should be able to resume, and I need to repeat this. :-(

Comment: Yes, of course. Each new instance of a device inherits the default settings – which include being able to wake the PC. Do you have hybrid standby enabled? Also, just do what I proposed overnight, otherwise you won't be able to find the actual culprit.

Comment: @DanielB As I said: I do not want to search culprits again and again - I want the PC off after hibernating. Even if I decide to switch USB ports. And currently there is no culprit, but it's still on.

Comment: If your computer wakes up, there's a reason. This reason can be easily located using the method I described. If you don't want Windows to be Windows, you should switch to something else. There's no way to change the default device behavior, sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By playing around with `powercfg -lastwake` , `powercfg -devicequery wake_armed` and `powercfg -devicedisablewake <device>` I could solve the problem of spurious wake ups. But the problem that the keyboard lights were still on after hibernate turned out to be a BIOS problem: in the setup there was an option "hibernate like soft off" which finally put the PC to its well deserved sleep.

Answer (score 1):

There are two steps you can take to achieve the desired behaviour.

1. Right-click on the "Start" button (the ball in the lower left) and select "Properties". Click the "Start Menu" tab and from the combo box next to the title "Power button action" select the behaviour you want, i. e. power off. This should already address your issue.
2. If you want to get rid of hibernation once and for all just open a command line interface as an administrator and type `powercfg /hibernate off`.

Comment: Thank you, but sorry - that's a misunderstanding. I do definitely want to hibernate the PC, not shutdown. But after Windows has written the RAM to disk, the PC has no business running anymore. I've added a clarification to the question.

Comment: I see, sorry. I am not aware of a solution to this particular use case.